# Where to save .py file so that I can recall it using "python - i < filename >"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

May I know where should i save my .py file so that I can call it back by using python -i  command? I am using Python IDLE version 3.1..

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the current working directory of your shell is. Often, this will be your home directory.

Comment: The user is probably on a windows machine.

Comment: @Jeroko: The same comments apply, although the environment variable for the home directory is less obviously named as `%USERPROFILE%`.

Answer (score 0):

You can include your .py file in the same directory as your input file - that would be the easiest.

You can alternately use the full path to the input file and keep your .py file wherever you want.